# travis-cargo, how to properly use the GH_TOKEN

Tags: rust, travis-ci

I'm confused when looking at the [github example](https://github.com/huonw/travis-cargo#example), the last line specifically:

```
language: rust
# necessary for `travis-cargo coveralls --no-sudo`
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libcurl4-openssl-dev
      - libelf-dev
      - libdw-dev

# run builds for all the trains (and more)
rust:
  - nightly
  - beta
  # check it compiles on the latest stable compiler
  - stable
  # and the first stable one (this should be bumped as the minimum
  # Rust version required changes)
  - 1.0.0

# load travis-cargo
before_script:
  - |
      pip install 'travis-cargo<0.2' --user &&
      export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

# the main build
script:
  - |
      travis-cargo build &&
      travis-cargo test &&
      travis-cargo bench &&
      travis-cargo --only stable doc
after_success:
  # upload the documentation from the build with stable (automatically only actually
  # runs on the master branch, not individual PRs)
  - travis-cargo --only stable doc-upload
  # measure code coverage and upload to coveralls.io
  - travis-cargo coveralls --no-sudo

env:
  global:
    # override the default `--features unstable` used for the nightly branch (optional)
    - TRAVIS_CARGO_NIGHTLY_FEATURE=nightly
    # encrypted github token for doc upload (see `GH_TOKEN` link above)
    - secure: "..."
```

So I understand I need to generate a token , and I have a token generated, but how do I actually tell travis-cargo to **use** this? I tried going through [this](http://www.hoverbear.org/2015/03/07/rust-travis-github-pages/#givingtravispermissions) link which the readme linked to, but I don't know how to apply this to travis-cargo specifically.

What exactly would I put in place of `"..."` after the `secure:` keyword? Not the token obviously, because that wouldn't be very secure, so what?

Comment: If you follow the instructions, it’s made abundantly clear. It’s in the “Giving Travis Permissions” section.

Comment: Thanks for the sassy reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why various guides about Travis suggest some arcane things with Ruby gems and manual encryption. I found that Travis built-in environment variables feature works nicely and does not require changing Travis manifest.

Basically, you need to go to your project settings on Travis, add `GH_TOKEN` environment variable and make sure that "Display value in build log" stays turned off:

[image: travis settings]

(the below line is how you add the variable, and the above one is how it looks after it is added)

Then, when building, Travis will add this variable to environment settings automatically, and its value will be evicted from the [build output](https://travis-ci.org/netvl/immeta/jobs/66758872):

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/netvl/immeta.git netvl/immeta

$ cd netvl/immeta

$ git checkout -qf 9aba89e5466627e190f27439c2240282bf2a9029

This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.

If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml

See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.

Setting environment variables from repository settings

$ export GH_TOKEN=[secure]

Setting environment variables from .travis.yml

$ export TRAVIS_CARGO_NIGHTLY_FEATURE=""
```

I think this way is much better than adding various encrypted tokens to the manifest.